# History tables for one to many relationships

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design, one-to-many

I need to track the version history of several entities, to be able to see the state of all its properties at any given point in its history, that includes their one to many relationships.

**Entities & Relationships:**

```
Person 
+++++++++++ 
id 
person_code 
name 
other
```

```
Address
+++++++++++
id
person_code
street
city
state
address_type
```

- **Person** and **address** has a one to many relationship, using *person_code* column as the FK.
- *address_type* is an enum, so one person can have many types of addresses. (e.g. residential, billing, permanent)
- **Address** record with each *address_type* can be updated separately (e.g. billing address can be updated without updating the residential address)

**The Problem:**
Need to maintain history for "Person" entity as well as "Address" entity
Along with that some mechanism is needed (revision or identifier) that could pinpoint the exact state of a **Person** and all her **Address** at that point of time.

**Approaches tried:**
If we use adjacency list for keeping the history for both the entities, then `person.getAddresses()` will give a lot of extra (historical) records.
Creating history tables will might increase the complexity of the solution.

If Person and Address tables are versioned separately, then a new table (say State) can be introduced to keep these versions and id of that new table would pinpoint the exact state at a given point of time.
But as the Person-Address relationship is one to many keeping the version of all addresses in a single record seems inappropriate.

Final approach that I've thought of:

1. Add unique `(person_code, revision)` to **Person**
2. Change FK of **Address** form `(person_code)` to `(person_code, revision)`
3. On each **Person** update, duplicate (with new revision) all **Address** entries for that **person_code**
4. Use  **Person** revision everywhere in the system

Can we somehow avoid the unnecessary duplication in step no. 3 ?

Please suggest what other approaches should be explored in this scenario.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
PersonSuper
+++++++++++ 
personsuper_key
```

(do not put person attributes in the above table, as weird as that sounds) (the above exists so you can keep referential integrity with address tables)

```
Person. (<<assumes "non historical) 
+++++++++++ 
person_key
personsuper_key FK
lastname
firstname

PersonArchive 
+++++++++++ 
personarchive_key
personsuper_key FK
person_key (the original value from Person.    person_key if you ever need that)
create_datestamp
version_ordinal
lastname
firstname
```

....

```
Address. (<<assumes "non historical) 
+++++++++++ 
address_key
personsuper_key FK

AddressArchive 
+++++++++++ 
addressarchive_key
address_key (<< the original Address.address_key, just in case)
personsuper_key FK
create_datestamp
version_ordinal
```

This will allow referential integrity with your archive (history) tables...and with a child table.

You can create a view to join the Person and PersonArchive tables (if ever needed to see it all together)

Comment: i would still need to store the information like what revision of person and addresses was used in a given transaction, how does this solve that problem?

Comment: So whenever there is an update to the Person table, you "copy" the pre-update row(s) into the PersonArchive.  Add a create-datestamp on the PersonArchive and optionally a Ordinal (int) column..that you can get max+1 for each copy you make into PersonArchive.

Comment: I added a few columns to try and illustration my previous comment

Comment: And would I increment person's revision along with the address's revision when one of the addresses gets updated??

Comment: Correct, technically you could get by with just the create-datestamp....but I like to add the version_ordinal...yes, this would be incremented 1, 2, 3,etc, etc.